# Retrieve Image from postgres database using PHP

Tags: php, linux, postgresql

I am working in PHP with Postgresql as backend. The database is already designed by others. Now I want to retrieve image from the database using PHP. But I'm not able to retrieve image from the database. I using this code to retrieve image but it shows only  unreadable characters in the webpage. Sometimes it shows a small icon (like when we get any image is not present in the webpage) but mostly it shows an empty page. The datatype from storing images is "bytea". The code I use to display the image is as follow:

```
$conn = pg_connect("user=xxxx password=xxxx dbname=xxxx host=xxxx");
$res = pg_query($conn, "SELECT scan_image FROM t1scandoc where image_srno='1'");
while(pg_fetch_array($res))
{
  if (pg_result($res,2))
  {
    WriteImageToFile(pg_result($res,0),$dir.pg_result($res,1),pg_result($res,2));
  }
}
```

Comment: We do not email answers. We post them under your question, as then other people can see them as well.

Answer (score 1):

You are not reading your result property.

1. `pg_result()` is not a function defined by the PostgreSQL Extension.
2. You are not storing the return value of [`pg_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/pg-fetch-array) in a variable.

The following code should output the `scan_image` value to the browser.

```
$conn = pg_connect("user=xxxx password=xxxx dbname=xxxx host=xxxx");
$res = pg_query($conn, "SELECT scan_image FROM t1scandoc where image_srno='1'");
if($row = pg_fetch_array($res)) // Output only one row, we can't output multiple
{
  echo $row['scan_image'];
}
```

I unfortunately do not know the file format of your `scan_image`. Don't forget to send the proper headers.